# send email with lumen, without set smtp credential in env file

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, lumen

I want to send email with lumen,

I have many different smtp credentials from where I have to send email with laravel, it is more then 1000

so I am not able to setup it from env file.

I have to define every time new credential before send email.

then how to pass it to lumen before send email

because in lumen sendMail() method we can pass array of arguments then how to manage it.

---

as per suggestion I have overwrite code as below,

I have used a below package in my composer.json file,

```
"illuminate/mail": "^5.2"
```

Then fire command in command prompt `composer update`

in bootstrap/app.php file register below class,

```
$app->register('\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider');
```

create mail.php file in cofig folder as below,

```
<?php

return [
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Mail Driver
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
      | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
      | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
      |
      | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
      |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
      |
     */
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | SMTP Host Address
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
      | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
      | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
      |
     */
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | SMTP Host Port
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
      | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
      | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
      |
     */
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Global "From" Address
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
      | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
      | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
      |
     */
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', ''),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', ''),
    ],
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
      | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
      | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
      |
     */
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | SMTP Server Username
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
      | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
      | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
      |
     */
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', ''),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | SMTP Server Password
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
      | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
      | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
      |
     */
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', ''),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Sendmail System Path
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
      | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
      | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
      |
     */
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Mail "Pretend"
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
      | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
      | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
      |
     */
    'pretend' => false,
    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

update my .env file for below,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
```

add mail.php file in bootstrap/app.php file as below,

```
$app->configure('mail');
```

create a provider to overwrite method `createSmtpDriver` from below file,

```
vendor\illuminate\mail\TransportManager.php
```

I have created provider as below,

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager;
use Session;

class EmailServiceProvider extends TransportManager
{
    /**
     * Create an instance of the SMTP Swift Transport driver.
     *
     * @return \Swift_SmtpTransport
     */
    protected function createSmtpDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']['mail'];

        // The Swift SMTP transport instance will allow us to use any SMTP backend
        // for delivering mail such as Sendgrid, Amazon SES, or a custom server
        // a developer has available. We will just pass this configured host.
        $transport = SmtpTransport::newInstance(
            Session::get('smtp_server'), $config['port']
        );

        if (isset($config['encryption'])) {
            $transport->setEncryption($config['encryption']);
        }

        // Once we have the transport we will check for the presence of a username
        // and password. If we have it we will set the credentials on the Swift
        // transporter instance so that we'll properly authenticate delivery.
        if (Session::has('smtp_user') && Session::get('smtp_user')) {
            $transport->setUsername(Session::get('smtp_user'));

            $transport->setPassword(Session::get('smtp_password'));
        }

        if (isset($config['stream'])) {
            $transport->setStreamOptions($config['stream']);
        }

        return $transport;
    }
}
```

and add that provider in bootstrap/app.php file as below,

```
$app->register(App\Providers\EmailServiceProvider::class);
```

from now in all the methods , it gives me error as below,

```
ErrorException in Manager.php line 77:
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in E:\xampp563\htdocs\delrentals-dashboard-api\vendor\illuminate\support\Manager.php on line 87 and defined
```

can anyone give me suggestion , what should I have to do to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to use multiple smtps.

```
 public function sendEmails()
{
    $smtps = Stmp::all();
    foreach ($smtps as $smtp)
    {
        config('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp');
        config('MAIL_USERNAME', $smtp->username);
        config('MAIL_HOST', $smtp->host);
        config('MAIL_PASSWORD', $smtp->password);
        config('MAIL_PORT', $smtp->port);
        config('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', $smtp->enc);

        //now send mail
        Mail::send('emails.mail', ['data' => $data], function  ($message) use($smtp) {
            $message->to('xyz@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')->subject('Laravel');
            $message->from($smtp->from_name, 'Name');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what  I have to do , if I dont want to create a view, and send html content in email,please can you tell me

Comment: this method will send html content in mail body     
$message->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html');
so code will be like this
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    // here what you want to do
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!'); // text/plain
    // or:
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html'); //  HTML rich messages
});

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the method createSmtpDriver inside namespace Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager

Comment: if I will overwrite it and any person will do composer update then it will be remove my code

Comment: it there any way that I can overwrite it from my code level instead of vendor

Comment: Yes you need to create your own version of MailServiceProvider and replace it in the config/app.php. In the Register method of your provider use your own TransportManager.

Comment: hi,gm, I have update my question ,in which I have override method, but gives me error, can you please look into it.